# Convert CTE to trigger

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have updated this CTE data into one table and I want that table automatically update every month so that table will be update with month data. Similarly, in the screenshot, it shows last month (Oct) data.

After every month automatically change table and update data. If we will implement trigger then whats the best trigger to apply in CTE how the code works with trigger. Anyone help me to write trigger with CTE.

```
WITH CTE_ABC AS 
(
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE 
               WHEN M.ActiveStart < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) 
                    AND M.ActiveEnd > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) 
                  THEN 1 ELSE 0 
             END) AS No_of_Live_Member, 
        SUM(CASE 
               WHEN M.ActiveEnd BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) 
                    AND DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,Getdate()), -1)  
                  THEN 1 ELSE 0 
            END) AS No_of_Member_Cancelled,
        M.HomeBranch,
        M.LocationName
    FROM
        AX.Mem M 
    GROUP BY
        M.HomeBranch, M.LocationName 
)
SELECT
    DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE())) AS Month, 
    DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE())) AS Year, 
    CAST(No_of_Member_Cancelled AS DECIMAL(10, 0)) /  CAST(NULLIF(No_of_Live_Member, 0) AS DECIMAL(10,0)) AS Current_Attrition_Rate,
    HomeBranch,
    LocationName
FROM
    CTE_ABC
WHERE
    No_of_Member_Cancelled / NULLIF(No_of_Live_Member, 0) IS NOT NULL
```

[image: Please see attached image]

Comment: Are you sure you want a trigger here? It sounds like you want this to run every month, wheras a trigger will be run every time the table is updated. Is that want you want?

Comment: yeah I want this query execute every month. How I will execute for every with updated data.but if trigger can do this, which is fine with this work. Anything that would be efficient here.

Comment: Well they are two separate choices. One would be to use the sql agent with a job scheduled every day, or week, or month, or whatever you need. Just create an update statement and you can schedule it, or even better wrap it in a stored proc and execute that. A trigger would require the update for every transaction, updating just the affected rows, which might affect performance. You would need to provide more details about what the triggering updates are, and what you want to update.

Comment: all data in select statement would be updated through trigger.

Comment: But updated in what table? You have given an example of the data the query returns, but not what you want to update with it. Some example of the schema would help. Also add a tag for whatever your database is. I assume sql-server as you have used "tsql"?

Comment: I have updated this data into Trends. Table. Same entries in trends table too for everymonth.

Comment: yes in tsql.Using Sql Server

Answer (score 0):

The ask is a little unclear, but if the question is how to perform an update based on a CTE, this is the syntax:

```
;with cte as (
    ... your query ...
)
update trends set ... whatever you need to update ...
from trends
join cte 
     on ... however you need to join between your cte and trends table
```

This query could be packaged up as a stored procedure, or entered directly in the SQL Agent and run every month, or as required.

Remember also  that you can have multiple CTEs if it helps, like the following. In your case your query after the CTE could be a second CTE, which is then used in the update.

```
;with cte1 as (
   ... you first query
)
,cte2 as (
   select blah from cte1
)
update trends set ...
from trends
join cte2 (etc)
```